# Regenerating a Rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Is there a simple way to regenerate a Rails page cache? Destroying the cache is easy:

```
Person.each.all do |person|
  expire_page(:controller => 'yql', :action => 'feed', :id => person.id)
end
```

This deletes the cached files in the public directory. Right after I destroy them though, I want to recreate them. I don't want to wait until they are viewed on the public web site.

Is there a simple *rails* way to do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to expire the page, then hit it using curl. Because curl generates a new request, the Passenger only needs enough memory to render one feed. It also avoids going round the caching system.

```
def recache
  Person.find_each :batch_size => 100 do |person|
    expire_page( :controller => 'yql', :action => 'feed', :id => person.id )
    system("curl #{yql_feed_url person.id}")
  end
  render :text => "re-caching was successful"
end
```

Of course, this is a linux only solution. It's also improtant to watch out for race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

So, for the record, here's what I did:

```
def recache
  Person.all.each do |person|
    path = MyApp::Application.config.action_controller.page_cache_directory + yql_feed_path(person)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))
    File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(render_to_string :action => 'feed')
    end
  end
  render :text => "re-caching was successful"
end
```

The feed is simply rendered and written to a file in the correct location. I'm not altogether happy about going round the caching system, but it suffices for now.

Answer (score 0):

To cache it you have to render it, and to render it you have to request it. I don't think you can do this without a request. You could always make one from Rails but that seems messy, or you could have an external process that does it with something like `curl` or the Ruby `curb` library.

Are you sure you have to do this?

Comment: Rendering the feed is expensive. It really needs to be done in the middle of the night.

Comment: Sounds like some `cron` and `curl` could do the job.

Comment: The issue is that the feeds are hit up very rapidly (much faster than they be generated) by an external API over which I have very limited control. I need the feeds ready, or it overloads my app, and my database falls over, ouch. Actually, I think I may have a solution...

Comment: So, for the record, here's what I did: